# Unexpected quoting in Apache Commons CSV

Tags: java, apache-commons-csv

While using Apache CSV with below maven dependency. I am getting unexpected results.

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Simple code is not working for me as expected.
Can anyone tell what is wrong here?

```
System.out.println(CSVFormat.DEFAULT.format("-10","10"));
```

Actual Output: `"-10",10`

Expected Output: `-10,10`

```
System.out.println(CSVFormat.DEFAULT.format("10","-10"));
```

Actual Output: `10,-10`

Expected Output: `10,-10`

```
System.out.println(CSVFormat.DEFAULT.format(".10","-10"));
```

Actual Output: `".10",-10`

Expected Output: `.10,-10`

```
System.out.println(CSVFormat.DEFAULT.format("+10","-10"));
```

Actual Output: `"+10",-10`

Expected Output: `+10,-10`

Comment: So the default format is not what you expect, and?

Comment: Yes, I think its bug in Apache CSV.

Comment: I would suggest you find some official documentation backing your bug idea and edit your question with that info

Comment: Thanks, I found similar bug in Apache CSV Jira https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CSV-148

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual results you listed above are legitimate CSV format (it is parseable even with the quotes), but I can see how it can look like an unexpected output.

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/apache/commons-csv/blob/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVPrinter.java#L232-L234) in `CSVPrinter.java`:

```
// TODO where did this rule come from?
if (newRecord && (c < '0' || (c > '9' && c < 'A') || (c > 'Z' && c < 'a') || (c > 'z'))) {
    quote = true;
}
```

This code will quote the first item in the row if it doesn't start with an alphanumeric character.

If you browse through the [code history](https://github.com/apache/commons-csv/blob/c9aeca5c39033c95c26c1475dcf0fd2ea86672e8/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVPrinter.java#L217-L225) on the class, you will find that this behavior has been there since the beginning of the repository (November 9, 2011).

I didn't notice any related bugs on the [issue tracker](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/issue-tracking.html), so you should open up a issue if you think the default behavior should be changed. Alternately, you could consider using a applying a [QuoteMode](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/archives/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#withQuoteMode-org.apache.commons.csv.QuoteMode-) using `CSVFormat.withQuoteMode()`.

Comment: Also consider posting your question on their user mailing list. Many Apache projects use them more often than SO. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/mail-lists.html